# method for assigning value on each field of value null

Tags: java

If I have an object with many fields, a part of them is null at beginning, is there a method to assign these variable by given a collection of value as input without repeating

```
(if x == null) x = a;
```

something like:

```
methodAssign(Object o, Collections c)
```

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re asking. Could you elaborate?

Comment: So you want to *default assign* all `null`-fields in a given object `o`? And in the `Collection` you have stored such default mappings that map for each of `o`s fields a default value? There is no such method but you can write it on your own. You can easily access fields of an object by using the **reflection API**, just type `myObject.getClass()`, the `Class<X>` object gives you access to many such methods. Just iterate the fields of the object using reflection, find `null`s and then search for default mappings in the collection, assign using reflection again.

Comment: @Zabuza Thanks. I'm using Spring now, is there the same method for entity class?

Comment: The **reflection API** is part of standard Java. You can call `getClass()` on **any object**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/)  you can create a method and pass your object and a hashmap with your fields name as a keys and values.

```
public Object methodAssign(Object object, HashMap<String, Object> fields) {
   for(Entry<String, Object> entry : fields.entrySet()) {
     if(BeanUtils.getProperty(object, entry.getKey()) == null)
         BeanUtils.setProperty(object, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
   }
   return object;
}
```

Example:

```
   Car carToInit = new Car();
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.add("field", 10);

    methodAssign(carToInit, map);
```

Comment: I think using regular methods of Javas **Reflection API** this code won't be that much larger, just a few additional lines. Could be worth mentioning both variants if you like.

Comment: Does it need to add a new library?  Is there something similar in spring? I'm using spring now.

Comment: Spring support [BeanUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html)   no need to add new library